# Getting cannot import name error when importing NudeClassifier from nudenet

Tags: python, import

I am getting an error when running the following code -

```py
from nudenet import NudeClassifier


def nudenetclf(df):
    classifier = NudeClassifier()
    for index in df.shape[0]:
        img_lst = df["images"].iloc[index]

        clf = classifier(img_lst)
        count = 0

        for key in list(clf.keys()):
            val = clf[key]
            if val["safe"] < val["unsafe"]:
                count += 1

        if count > 0:
            print(df["url"].iloc[index])
```

On running above code I get an error  - `ImportError: cannot import name 'NudeClassifier'`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Sounds like `nudenet` is not installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `NudeClassifier` without importing it. so,

Import `NudeClassifier` like this:

```
from nudenet import NudeClassifier
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to write NudeClassifier, in the original code it is written as `from nudenet import NudeClassifier`. And I am still getting the error.

Comment: What is your new error? @MaujMishra

Comment: There is no new error, its the same `cannot import name NudeClassifier`.

Comment: Your python version? @MaujMishra

Comment: I got it, my python file name was also "nudenet.py". That's why it was getting confused.

Comment: Oh, tricky, happy that you found out the problem.